# How to filter JSON dictionary in SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I'm using SwiftyJSON to get a list and printing it out to a TableView.
My issue is I can't filter this dictionary, I tried to make a for loop to remove the unwanted elements (or even pushing a new element), but I couldn't find a way to remove or pushing an element with a JSON type that SwiftyJSON provides.

```
var FilteredTripList:JSON = TripsList
for (key: String, Trip: JSON) in TripsList {
    if String(stringInterpolationSegment: Trip["TripFrom"]) != SearchFilter["From"]!
    || String(stringInterpolationSegment: Trip["TripTo"]) != SearchFilter["To"]! {
            // I'm hoping for something like the line below
            // FilteredTripList[key.toInt()!].remove()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is your TripsList? is it a JSONArray? Or a JSONObject? Because your for loop is for JSONObjects which are key based... JSONArrays are index based... So I need to know what type TripList is?

Comment: It's JSON from SwiftyJSON

Comment: Yes, that it is a JSON is clear, but is it a JSONArray, or a JSONObject? It only can be one of those types?

Comment: How can I know? The variable made by Alamofire
The code is: Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)
  .responseJSON

Comment: Could you NSLog the responded JSON from your request, and post it in here? If I see the JSON, I can tell you what to do next

Comment: Also, is it a requirement to use SwiftyJSON? Or ist it ok if I write you a simpler Class that you can query easily? As I see in your Profile, you have multiple unsolved Questions... If you want to, post me your, or an eMailAdress, I will send you an eMail and we can clear this problems?

Comment: Oh, I got it, it's JSON array, thanks man I can make the custom class but I have a deadline, I was just wanted to make sure that SwiftyJSON array doesn't have remove function, I guess I will just make a for loop to put the JSON into a NSMutablearray or something

Comment: Alright, yes thats a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know swifty json, because I always use the native way with NSJSONSerialization... So I have to guess

Please change this line

```
FilteredTripList[key.toInt()!].remove()
```

To this line

```
FilteredTripList.removeValueForKey(key)
```

And write me what happened

Comment: Nope, tried those, not working. I need something works with SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
FilteredTripList.dictionaryObject?.removeValueForKey(key.toInt()!)
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way to filter the [JSON] was doing this:

```
        self.places = self.locals.filter({ (json) -> Bool in
            return json["monthlyPurchasesLocalCount"].intValue > 0;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code snippet if you are using SwiftyJSON,

it works perfectly for me. I got it after a lots of tries.

```
let jsonObj = some JSON 
let jobj = jsonObj.arrayValue
if !jobj.isEmpty {
   let j = jobj.filter({ (json) -> Bool in
       return json["country"].stringValue == "US"; })
   print ("filterdData: \(j)")
}
```

**Note: jobj should be .arrayValue, otherwise it won't work.**